# Twitter bootsrap model fade on clicking link_to but black fade appears on the modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, fade

I try to fade modal on clicking the link but black fade appear on the modal popup following is my code of modal and link

clicking on the following link modal fade

```
 <%= link_to 'New Trade','#myModal', :class => 'btn',:style => 'float:right;', :role => 'button', :data =>{ :toggle => 'modal', :keyboard => true, :backdrop => true } %>
```

And following is modal code

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" keyboard="true">
    <%= simple_form_for @trade_category, :url => create_trade_category_path(@trade_category), :html => { :class => 'form_height'} do |f| %>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">New Trade Category</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <%= f.input :name,:lable => false, :autofocus => true, :placeholder =>"Trade category name", :class=> 'input-block-level' %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <%= f.submit "Create Trade category", :class=> "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

And I got the following out put 
[image]

CSS are as under

.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #00000}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1050;}

Comment: did you mess with any z-index?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved in application file the parent div navbar position is fixed so I remove the position fixed and now it is working fine.